# use numpy to join two columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have two text files `ra.txt` and `dec.txt`, each containig one column. I would like to join these two columns in a third file with one column, as follows:

**ra.txt**

```
115.07433  
114.75551
114.85937
111.18574
192.78617
189.71056
0.47592
2.22369
2.97497
5.44140
0.29367
308.83178
```

**dec.txt**

```
-88.84627
-88.68575
-88.68499
-88.63843
-88.70691
-88.69978
-87.12709
-87.12417
-87.11521
-86.95877
-86.94902
-87.04636
```

I would like the **output file** to be:

```
115.07433-88.84627
114.75551-88.68575
114.85937-88.68499
111.18574-88.63843
192.78617-88.70691
189.71056-88.69978
0.47592-87.12709
2.22369-87.12417
2.97497-87.11521
5.44140-86.95877
0.29367-86.94902
308.83178-87.04636
```

Could you help me do that, please?

Comment: If you're dealing with text and text files, there is no point in using numpy for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), [`numpy.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) and [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) for this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a1 = np.loadtxt('ra.txt')
>>> a2 = np.loadtxt('dec.txt')
>>> np.savetxt('out.txt', np.column_stack((a1, a2)), delimiter=' ', fmt='%.5f')
>>> !cat out.txt
115.07433 -88.84627
114.75551 -88.68575
114.85937 -88.68499
111.18574 -88.63843
192.78617 -88.70691
189.71056 -88.69978
0.47592 -87.12709
2.22369 -87.12417
2.97497 -87.11521
5.44140 -86.95877
0.29367 -86.94902
308.83178 -87.04636
```

Comment: I do it as you said. But there is a space between the two numbers from the two files. I want to be one number and there is no space. Could t be?

Comment: @user2154410 Then change the `delimiter` to `''`.